# Playwright: Take screen shot after every click

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, automation, playwright, playwright-test

I am new to playwright.I was hoping that i can acheive this with page.evaluate because in the docs i read "page.evaluate() API can run a JavaScript function in the context of the web page and bring results back to the Playwright environment".

Below is my attempt which gives "TypeError: listner is not a function"

```
    const listner =  await page.evaluate(()=>{
        return document.body.addEventListener;
    });
    listner('click',()=>{
        //here i plan to call page.screenshot method
    })
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong or how to acheive this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create addEventListener for click and listen for it using `page.on`.

Here's an example which records for all click within 10 seconds on google homepage

```js
import { test } from "@playwright/test";

test(`StackOverflow`, async ({ page }) => {
  await page.addInitScript(() => {
    window.addEventListener("click", () => console.log("customClickEvent"));
  });

  page.on("console", (message) => {
    if (message.text() === "customClickEvent") {
      page.screenshot({ path: `test-results/${Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000)}.png` });
    }
  });

  await page.goto("https://www.google.com/");
  await page.waitForTimeout(10_000);
});
```